# Symfony 5 : how to create (in a database) with ajax and without form

Tags: symfony

I have this button and I'd like to make it so when I click on it, there's an ajax that goes directly into my create function in symfony but doesn't display any form (at this point I already have the informations I need). But I have no idea how to get the form that way.

I used to do

```
$livre = new Livre();
$livre->setUuid(Uuid::v4());

$form = $this->createForm(LivreType::class, $livre);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

But obviously I can't use LivreType::class anymore cause I don't need the form.
I keep searching for information about this but I can't find anything

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have multiple way of doing it.
I'm gonna show you a simple way to do it, and try to adapt or find a better way for doing it!

---

**LivreController.php**

```php
    /**
     * @Route(path="/livre/create", methods={POST})
     */
    public function createNewLivre(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $json       = $this->getJSON($request);
        $newLivre   = new Livre();

        // Set to your new entity parameters...
        $em->persist($newLivre);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->json([
            'message' => 'A new Livre has been added.' // It could also be empty if you don't want to manage anything
        ]);
    }

    private function getJSON(Request $request)
    {
        $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            throw new HttpException(400, 'json invalid');
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

**script.js**

```js
let button = document.getElementById('livreCreatorButton');

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/livre/create', {
        method: 'POST', // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: '{}',
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I managed to make it all work like I wanted :)